# Javascript Array`s

Tags: javascript

Just want to loop an array in javascript.

This is my base array

```
var family = ["1A+1C","1A+2C","1A+3C","2A","2A+1C","2A+2C","2A+3C"];
```

and i want the ageset0 to ageset6 array values in to be fetched as per the slot. currenlty the ageset0 values are getting printed all the way

how to achieve it. thanks in advance.

this is the sample page.

http://jsfiddle.net/baVU2/2/

Comment: are those hex, and if so to what do they refer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question then I think you want something like this (you want both arrays `ageset0 and ageset1` to be printed, currently there is only 'ageset0' is being printed through the loop)

```
for(i=0; i<family.length; i++)
{
    var max=Math.max(ageset0.length, ageset1.length);
    for(k=0; k<max; k++)
    {              
        var a=age[k] ? age[k] : '', a0=ageset0[k] ? ageset0[k] : '',
        a1=ageset1[k] ? ageset1[k] : '', f=family[k] ? family[k] : '';
        document.write("STARCOMP , "+a+ " , "+a0+" ,"+a1+", "+f+"<br>");
        document.write("<br>");
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/baVU2/5/).

**Update:** (From the comment)

```
var allArrays=[ageset0, ageset1, ageset2, ageset3, ageset4, ageset5,ageset6];
var a=age, f=family;
for(x=0; x<allArrays.length; x++)
{
    var ag=allArrays[x];
   for(k=0; k<ag.length; k++)
   {              
       document.write("STARCOMP , "+a[k]+ " , "+ag[k]+", "+f[k]+"<br>");
       document.write("<br>");
   }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/baVU2/6/).

Comment: ya but if the second set is started like the 2nd occurance of "535" is started then at that time i want the a0 shd be from ageset1 ... like wise it shd keep on increment till ageset6. any way thanks a lot for your try .. happy

Comment: Sorry I'm too confused now, you mentioned only `ageset0 and ageset1` in your question but now i didn't get it.

Comment: var ageset0 =["10315","11371","16000","18191","22135","35304"];
var ageset1 =["12303","13506","21888","23045","26494","41562"];                                                                        STARCOMP , 535 , 10315 , 1A+1C

STARCOMP , 3645 , 11371 , 1A+1C

STARCOMP , 4650 , 16000 , 1A+1C

STARCOMP , 5155 , 18191 , 1A+1C

STARCOMP , 5660 , 22135 , 1A+1C

STARCOMP , 6165 , 35304 , 1A+1C

STARCOMP , 535 , 10315 , 1A+2C

STARCOMP , 3645 , 11371 , 1A+2C

STARCOMP , 4650 , 16000 , 1A+2C

STARCOMP , 5155 , 18191 , 1A+2C

STARCOMP , 5660 , 22135 , 1A+2C

STARCOMP , 6165 , 35304 , 1A+2C

Comment: i am not sure hw to arrange dat but if u look at it closely... the array ageset0 to ageset6 will have some values which shd be displayed in my above format. hope u will get this time..

Comment: @Harry, [Is this ok](http://jsfiddle.net/baVU2/6/)?

Comment: tHANKS A LOT Heera. exactly wat i wanted... thanks a lot. :)

Comment: hey if u see the o/p "1A+1C" and "1A+2C" is getting changed in the first lot itself. actually it should be like "1A+1C" for the first slot from 535 - 6165 and for 2nd slot it shd be "1A+2C"

Comment: [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/baVU2/12/) and let me know if it's ok.

Comment: Thanks man its great. i am just developing a mobile app...but thanks for your large help on this :)

Comment: i have been banned from asking any more question. the system is not allowing to post any more msgs... i have always acknowledged the my replies. can some one up for me pls.